# Other VM than Dalvik possible for Android Applications

Tags: java, android, oracle, mobile, dalvik

Is it possible to include a different JVM into an application and have the app run within this JVM rather than the Dalvik VM provided by Android?
I'm asking because Oracle's ADF Mobile uses its own JVM both on Android and iOS but doesn't specify exactly how they do it. It is supposed to be based on a J2ME CDC VM.

My colleague thinks they run it within the dalvik VM and add in the apk those libraries needed to achieve Java ME CDC specs.

If it were truly a completely seperate JVM then, theoretically, it should also be possible to include a Java EE JVM and toss some reusable business logic from backends in there right?

Comment: I suspect they bring up a real JVM with C using invocation api / JNI, and then load their stuff into it :)

Comment: This seems entirely possible to me but one thing to consider will be the cost of interoperation. I suspect that writing the necessary interop code from the dalvik vm to your custom vm will not be easy. Since your business logic is Java, why not just compile it to run on the dalvik vm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can even add a support for C# in theory, meaning that you can add a CLR/CLI support, or whatever language or VM you like.

All the Android components are really modular and the entire OS is customizable, the problem is that this requires a lot of money, time, know-how and most-likely, patent-trolling.

[**click me for a youtube reply**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkPiXRNee7A#t=47m20s)

this is from an official talk about Android.

Comment: Well oracle has all of the above money time and know how so its possible they wrote their very own VM directly against the kernel. Great thats all i needed to know. On iOS they wrote a jvm in objective c code which is most likely just a normal jvm compiled with x code since C is a subset of objective C. Pretty interesting stuff but idk why they did do a j2me one not one that can actually be useful in the business app dev context

Comment: @user1170940 can't answer to that, i really don't know this product but some J2ME profile supports JNI which can be used to code in C/C++ and so you can extend this platform with more possibilities.